# How to change the breadcrumbs separator?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is it possible to change the breadcrumbs separator from `/` to something else? eg: `>`

Or should I just ignore zurb and do it the traditional way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your css:

```
.breadcrumbs li:not(:last-child)::after
{
     content:">";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `/` separators are defined via css in [`foundation/scss/foundation/components/modules/_ui.scss`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/27cc595496233b42bf0b8a212811d32eb081aa94/scss/foundation/components/modules/_ui.scss):

```
ul.breadcrumbs { 
    li:before { content: "/"; color: #aaa; }
    li:first-child:before { content: " "; }
}
```

To change it you need to override this CSS in your `app.css` file:

```
ul.breadcrumbs li:before { content: ">"; }
```